# Emission material not showing in render EEVEE

Tags: eevee-render-engine, emission

[image]
[image]

I don't know what's wrong with it but I have gave it a emission but it doesn't show up in the render view.

Comment: You have to add Volume Scatter to the World or add a Volume object around the emissive meshes. If you add it to the world, the background won't be transparent anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bloom pass and composite it in the Compositor.

Comment: Illustrate this if you could.

Comment: Hi. Please add some extra details as to *how* the user could do this. Thanks.

Comment: This video will guide you properly https://youtu.be/eQ1InBbRcco

Answer (score 0):

Well eevee does not support true emmision
Either use cycles or use the bloom checkbox in the render setting to fake the emmision,it may work depending on the result you are going for